# CMOS vs BiCMOS technology nodes comparison

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, vlsi

I am trying to make a comparison between several technology nodes. More specifically I want to compare 28nm, 40nm, 65nm CMOS and BiCMOS processes. However I cannot find papers that compare some of these processes or at least several papers that present individually information for these nodes. Am I searching in a wrong way? Can someone guide me to the rigth way? I would like for example to compare the \$f_t\$, \$f_{max}\$, noise figures, intrisic gain etc

Thank you in advance

Comment: What parameters do you want to compare?

Comment: A lot of that info may be company proprietary to the various fab houses.